# Javascript recursion within a class using JSON data

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a JS navbar using a recursion method to work in a class context using a JSON data. and also i want to getter and setter a new value in a JSON using a class.

```js
var defaultAdd = document.getElementById('dropdown-select');
 var optionVal = [{
         name: "Animals",
         child: [{
                 name: "Dog",
                 child: [{
                         name: "Huskey"
                     },
                     {
                         name: "German Shephard"
                     }
                 ]
             },
             {
                 name: "Fish",
                 child: [{
                         name: "Whale"
                     },
                     {
                         name: "Shark"
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "Metal",
         child: [{
                 name: "Hard",
                 child: [{
                         name: "Gold"
                     },
                     {
                         name: "Iron"
                     },
                     {
                         name: "Silver"
                     }
                 ]
             },
             {
                 name: "Soft",
                 child: [{
                         name: "Alluminium"
                     },
                     {
                         name: "Mercury"
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "Cloths",
         child: [{
                 name: "Resin",
             }, 
             {
                 name: "Cotton",
             },
             {
                 name: "Linen",
             },
             {
                 name: "Denim",
             }
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "Lead",
     }
 ]
 var array = ['<ul class="lvl-1">'];
 navbar(optionVal, 0);

 function navbar(optionVal, count) {
     array.push('<li>' + optionVal[count].name + '<ul class="lvl-2">');
     for (var i in optionVal[count].child) {
         array.push('<li>' + optionVal[count].child[i].name + '<ul class="lvl-3">');
         for (var k in optionVal[count].child[i].child) {
             array.push('<li>' + optionVal[count].child[i].child[k].name + '</li>');
         }
         array.push('</ul></li>');
     }
     array.push('</ul></li>');

     if (count >= optionVal.length - 1) {
         return false;
     } else {
         navbar(optionVal, count + 1)
     }
 }
 defaultAdd.innerHTML = array.join("");
```

```css
ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 35%;
        border-right: 4px solid #eac320;
    }

    li {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background: #34495e;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 24px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        transition: 0.1s all ease-in-out;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    li:hover {
        background: #2dcc70;
    }

    li ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        display: none;
    }

    li:hover ul.lvl-2,
    ul.lvl-2 li:hover ul.lvl-3 {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="dropdown-select"></div>
```

Here i make a navbar using a recursive function and i want to make a recursive using a Class and also implement a getter and setter a new value in a JSON. 
**So anyone have idea how to use Class function and their getter and setter?**

Answer (score 0):

Basic getter setter syntax with class

```js
class X {
   constructor() { this.x = 1 }
   get getter() { return this.x }
   set setter(x) { return this.x=x }
}

var CX = new X();
console.log(".getter + .getter:", CX.getter + CX.getter);
console.log(".setter = 2:", CX.setter = 2);
console.log(".getter * .getter:", CX.getter * CX.getter);
```